# How to set values from an array objects to dynamic rows in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a row containing two columns which is dynamically generated 18 times. It is easy for me to grab the values from each row with their index and save it but I am not sure how to load values from a database to these dynamically generated rows. I just started learning ReactJS and I'm stuck here. Please help, thanks.

Code:

```
function Repeat(props) {
            let items = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < props.numTimes; i++) {
                items.push(props.children(i));
            }
            return <div>{items}</div>;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <form name="survey1form" className="contactform" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                        <div className="container" >

                            <div style={divStyle} className="row">
                                <div className="col-sm-3">Relative</div>
                                <div className="col-sm-2" />
                                <div className="col-sm-3">Relative Cancer Type</div>
                            </div>

                            <Repeat numTimes={18}>
                                {(index) => <div key={index} className="row" style={ddStyle} id={"relative_row_" + index}>
                                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                                        <select name={"relative_id_" + index} id={"relative_id_" + index}   className="form-control input-sm">
                                            {relativedata.map((reldata, i) => (<option key={i} value={reldata.value}>{reldata.display}</option>)
                                            )}

                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-sm-2" />
                                    <div className="col-sm-3">
                                        <select name={"relative_ca_type_" + index} id={"relative_ca_type_" + index} key={index} className="form-control input-sm">
                                            {cadata.map((cdata, i) => (<option key={i} value={cdata.value}>{cdata.display}</option>)
                                            )}
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                }
                            </Repeat>
```

this is my load function to get the data:

```
 Function loadId(enterpressed) {
        if (!enterpressed) return;
        var text = $('#idnumber').val();
        $.post("/main/pub/display/realtiveData.aspx", { id: text },

            (data) => {
                var jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    getRelative: jsondata.getRelative,
                }),
                    console.log(jsondata.getRelative);
            });
    }

getRelative log containing data from db :


 (18) […]
    ​0: {…}
    ​​comments: null
    ​​date_entered: null
    ​​date_modified: null
    ​​inits: null
    ​​patient_id: 1211
    ​​person_id: null
    ​​relative_ca_type1: 2
    relative_id: 94
    relative_sex: "M"
    sibling_num: 1
    status: null
    <prototype>: Object { … }
    1: Object { patient_id: 1211, relative_id: 2, relative_sex: "M", … }
    ​.......................................
    17: Object { patient_id: 1211, relative_id: 1, relative_sex: "M", … }
    length: 18
```

I need to assign each value for `relative_id` and `relative_ca_type1` to the two dynamically generated columns `(relative_id_" + index and relative_ca_type_" + index)`.

[Screenshot of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhzjG.png)

[Refereed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz57i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didnt undestand what you are trying to do but you could do something like this

```
<div>
  {data.map(item => <Row key={item.id}><Col>...</Col><Col>...</Col></Row>)}
</div>
```

Meaning instead of creating excatly 18 rows DO NOT create rows unless you have array of your data objects, than use the array.map() to creat adequte number of rows while iterating over the data objects.

Side note: Do not use array index as key in react. Key prop informas react wheter unmount/remount the component. When Key changes the component gets destroyed and mounted once again (thus going through lifecycle as if it was mounted for the first time). Using array index is counterproductive as it will never change unless the aray become smaller than the key (in which case the component gets unmounted nontheless).